# Sheaf relative to a presheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, topological-stacks

I was looking at these notes https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503247.pdf and it keeps using the phrase "sheaf relative to a presheaf" (i.e. definition 3.3). What does this mean? An online search has not revealed anything and I can't make any sense out of this.

Comment: Searching the document, I can't find a single instance of that phrase.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine definition 3.3 ("presheaf of groups relative to a presheaf"), beginning of section 3.4 ("a presheaf of groups relative to...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it means nothing. The author wants to highlight with "When $X$ is relative to $S$" that a certain construction $F(X,S)$ (depending on these objects) results in an object which is defined over $S$, i.e. admits a morphism to $S$. (This is the usual meaning in algebraic geometry of being "over $S$" or "relative to $S$".)

In the case of the classifying stack of a group $G$ (which is Definition 3.3 in the mentioned paper) we can take any base scheme $S$ and define $[S/G]$ as the stack associated to the "trivial" groupoid $[G \times S \rightrightarrows S]$. And even more generally, if $S$ is any presheaf (on the given site $\mathsf{C}$ in the paper) of sets and $G$ is a presheaf of groups, we can define $[S/G]$ as the sheaf associated to $[G \times S \rightrightarrows S]$, which thus is a sheaf of sets (on the same site) and clearly admits a morphism to $S$. Notice that we have $[S/G] = S \times [\star/G] = S \times BG$.

Comment: Is one of the maps $G \times S \rightrightarrows S$ inherited from the map $G \to S$? I am also not sure why this sheaf is referenced as trivial

Comment: There is no map $G \to S$.

Comment: Didn't you say that is what it means for $G$ to be relative to $S$?

Comment: There is a morphism $[S/G] \to S$. Please read again.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, to be fair, I find the author's terminology here confusing as well. Perhaps it is worthwhile to mention that there *is* a relative construction of this kind. If $T$ is another presheaf (usually a scheme, at least in algbraic geometry) and $G$ is a group object in the category of presheaves over $T$, and $S$ is again any presheaf over $T$, we can form $[S/G/T]$ as the sheaf associated to the groupoid $[G \times_T S \rightrightarrows S]$ over $T$. For (a bit) more details, see "Champs algébriques" by Gérard Laumon and Laurent Moret-Bailly.

Comment: About your question why the groupoid is considered to be trivial. Well, in the simplest possible case (the site is just one point), we have a set $S$ and a group $G$, and form a groupoid whose objects are the points of $S$ and whose morphisms $s \to t$ exist only when $s=t$ and then $\mathrm{Hom}(s,s) = G$. Again, this can be written as $S \times G$ where $S$ is seen as a discrete category and $G$ is seen as a one-object groupoid. Both constructions are "trivial" groupoids, so to speak. Groupoids are more "non-trivial" when they also admit morphisms between different objects.